# How to import MIN/SUM in Intellij and suppress log4j warning for flink case in Intellij?

Tags: apache-flink

I'm learning official document whose examples are always not complete.

So,I'm trying to complete the example.

This example is from [Aggregate on Grouped Tuple DataSet](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/batch/dataset_transformations.html#projection-of-tuple-dataset)

```
import org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple2;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.tuple.Tuple3;
import org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment;
public class AggregateonGroupedTupleDataSet {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
        String rootPath = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        DataSet<Tuple3<Integer, String,Double>> input =env.readCsvFile("file://"+rootPath+"/"+"aggregate.    csv").types(Integer.class, String.class,Double.class);
        DataSet<Tuple3<Integer, String, Double>> output = input
                .groupBy(1)        // group DataSet on second field
                .aggregate(SUM, 0) // compute sum of the first field
                .and(MIN, 2);      // compute minimum of the third field


    }
}
```

Question1:

How to import MIN/SUM in Intellij?

Question2:

How can I suppress warning for above flink example in intellij?

log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger
(org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment).

log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.

log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.

Thanks for your help~!

Comment: You've changed your question so that my answer no longer applies; please don't do this. The purpose of stack overflow is to collect questions and answers to those questions so that others can benefit. Now my answer is useless, since it doesn't respond to your question. Also, your updated question is unclear -- what warnings do you see?

Comment: Thanks for your attention,because after I propose this question,I also look for its answer,and I almost find the answer with @DavidAnderson at the same time.

Comment: I have updated my description and I have upvoted your answer,Thanks for your help~!

Comment: I did not mean to abuse StackOverflow, for me,it's a long time before I fresh the page (at least
 30 seconds),I'm NOT in US/UK,so when I find `Alt+Enter`to get the result you said,I modify the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your IDE can help you find these; that's one reason why the documentation doesn't spell out all of the imports. But MIN and SUM come from

```
import static org.apache.flink.api.java.aggregation.Aggregations.MIN;
import static org.apache.flink.api.java.aggregation.Aggregations.SUM;
```

Comment: I have recovered the question to its origin,your answer is perfect,Thanks~!